# SMTP with PHP sending always fail response bad

Tags: php, smtp

I have a problem in sending through the SMTP in the PHP
I tried many things , change smtp , change code , search for new things but always the same result

the code

```
    require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
if ($_GET['check'] == "1") {
$smtpserver = "";
$smtpport = "";
$smtpuser = "";
$smtppass = "";
$from = "";
$to = "";
$msag = "test / $smtpserver - $smtpport - $smtpuser - $smtppass";
$datamasii= date("D M d, Y - g:i a");
try {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //New instance, with exceptions enabled
    $mail->IsSMTP();                           // tell the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Port       = $smtpport;                    // set the SMTP server port
    $mail->Host       = $smtpserver; // SMTP server
    $mail->Username   = $smtpuser;     // SMTP server username
    $mail->Password   = $smtppass;            // SMTP server password
    $mail->setFrom($from, 'test');
    $mail->AddAddress($to, "Member");
    $mail->Subject  = "test - $smtpserver $datamasii";
    $mail->MsgHTML($msag);
    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
    $mail->Send();
    echo "OK";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo "NO";
}


}
```

the response always no

Comment: The response certainly is not "no". What _is_ the error you get? What is contained in `$e`? Why do you throw away that information? Use at least `$e->getMessage()`...

Comment: @arkascha i always get "no"

Comment: Well yes, because you throw away the error and print "No" instead of the valuable information you get.

Comment: this is $e @arkascha -- exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.' in /home/a9769858/public_html/class.phpmailer.php:781
Stack trace:
#0 /home/a9769858/public_html/class.phpmailer.php(666): PHPMailer->SmtpConnect()
#1 /home/a9769858/public_html/class.phpmailer.php(537): PHPMailer->SmtpSend('Date: Sat, 15 N...', '--b1_ed68bccb32...')
#2 /home/a9769858/public_html/tet.php(27): PHPMailer->Send()
#3 {main}

Comment: See, there is a helpful error message. Can you try manually to connect to the smtp server you specified? For example using `telnet smtpserver smtp` (where smtpserver obviously is the server you specified). What happens?

Comment: PLEASE DELETE THAT COMMENT NOW! You should never post such stuff here!

Comment: @arkascha bro this is okay :) i have 400 smtp i just want to solve this

Comment: Well, there is a smtp server listening, so looking at the error message you get I'd say: this is a network problem. Most likely a firewall inbetween, or a faulty name resolution. You should try manually from the system the code runs on.

Comment: mm the php code is correct ? @arkascha

Comment: At least it tries to connect and fails. That is what the error message says. (that is, _IF_ you specified the correct credentials in those variables at the top. I assume you left that out by purpose).

Comment: But again: remove that comment. Everyone will be able to send endless SPAM messages using your smtp server. Or at least change those credentials now. Delete it WHILST YOU STILL CAN. There is a timeout for that of 5 minutes.

Comment: @arkascha maybe port 25 is closed ?

Comment: Well it is not closed when I try manually.

Comment: i mean in my server @arkascha

Comment: Unlikely that you block _outgoing_ traffic, unless you specifically implemented such a rule (assuming that by "my server" you are referring to the system executing the php code). Also note that such connectiong would _not_ use port 25 on your system, but a dynamic port. Port 25 is addressed on the smtp servers side.

Comment: Any reason why you refuse to test manually?

Comment: it's working bro :) i changed the server and it worked thanks alot :)) - the problem was in my server (that the php code on it) @arkascha one last thing (how to put a timeout ?)

Comment: A timeout for what? Connecting to the server? There already is one configured inside php. Apart from that: consult the documentation, I'd say. That is what it has been written for.